# Why do I get so precise floating-point number from std::cout?

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout

The program

```
int main ()
{
    long long ll = LLONG_MAX;
    float f = ll;
    std::cout << ll << '\n';
    std::cout << std::fixed << f << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775808.000000
```

How is it possible? If 23-bit mantissa can have only 8,388,607 maximum value, why does cout output a 64-bit number?

Comment: If you'll notice, you don't get the same value for both values, so it isn't precise, it's an approximation

Comment: @NathanOliver, relatively to what I expect, it's precise, but yes, you're right

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: 1 x 2^63 doesn't need more than 23 bits in the mantissa.

Comment: Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stored 2^63-1 in a float, which was rounded to 2^63 = 9223372036854775808. The powers of 2 are exactly representable.

The nearest number which is exactly representable is 2^63 + 2^40 = 9223373136366403584.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why + 2^40 gives the next representable number?

Comment: @olekstolar: 63 - 23 = 40.

Comment: It doesn't explain for me. If exponent bits have a value of 63 and a mantissa has 1, how can the next representable be something else than 2*2^63 or 1*2^64?

Comment: @olekstolar: the decimal point is on the left. Check the definition of the mantissa.

Answer (score 1):

`long long` for you is a 64 bit data type so that means `LLONG_MAX` has a value of `2^63 - 1`.  You are right in that this can't be stored in a `float` which only has 23 bits of mantissa, but `2^63`, which is one more than `LLONG_MAX` is easily stored in a float.  It stores `2` in the mantissa and `63` in the exponent and there you have it.

Comment: You probably mean 1.0000... in the mantissa, actually stored as .00000...

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm ignoring how it's actually encoded.  I'm just demonstrating that it isn't really anything to store a `2^63` in a float exactly.